# faster graph traversal algorithms compared to dfs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have an undirected unweighted graph represented using adjacency matrix where each node of the graph represents a space partition (e.g. State) while the edges represent the neiborhood relationship (i.e. neighboring states sharing common boundaries). My baseline algorithm uses DFS to traverse the graph and form subgraphs after each step (i.e. adding the new node visited which would result in a bunch of contiguous states). With that subgraph I perform a statistical significance test on certain patterns which exist in the nodes of the graph (i.e. within the states).

At this point I am essentially trying to make the traversal step faster.

I was wondering if you all could suggest any algorithm or resources (e.g. research paper) which performs graph traversal computationally faster than DFS.

Thanks for your suggestion and your time!

Comment: Your question is ill-formed. "Graph traversal" simply means traversing a graph. What problem are you trying to solve? What are these "future computations"? If your only goal is to visit all the nodes, the next question would be how do you represent your graph? You can simply store an array of all nodes...

Comment: In practice A* is very good.

Comment: The best way to make it faster is to not traverse the whole graph. This reflects the question back to yourself: What do you need to do? Can you solve your problem without traversing the whole graph (=visiting every vertex)? If not, then you can't really get algorithmically faster than DFS. If yes, then look into search algorithms.

Comment: @LiorKogan Thanks for the response. I have added some more details to explain the future computations.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Thanks for the response. I will look it up.

Comment: @Berthur Thanks for the response. I have added some more details to explain the future computations. I think I need to traverse the whole graph for my problem.

Comment: @goaroundmsp That is more informative but at least to me it's still not quite clear what the actual problem is. I would recommend to either give us a formal problem description, or alternatively show us your code. The are cases where DFS is the best approach, and cases where it is not.

Comment: This might be a better question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The key question, which others have asked, is "Do you have to traverse the entire graph?" If the answer is yes, then you can do depth-first or breadth-first, but either one is going to require O(N): you have to visit every node. If you don't have to traverse the entire graph, then what criteria do you use to limit the set of nodes you traverse? Also, are you certain that the traversal is the cause of your slowdown? Traversal is simple and usually very fast. You don't show any code, so it's impossible for us to say where your actual performance problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Most graph algorithms contain "for given vertex `u`, list all its neighbors `v`" as a primitive. Not sure, but sounds like you might want to speed up this piece. Indeed, each country has only few neighbors, typically much less than the total number of countries. If this is the case, replace [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) graph representation with [adjacency lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

Note that the algorithm itself (DFS or other) will likely remain the same, with just a few changes where it uses this primitive.